# Non-Jedi Force Training?

Tags: star-wars

Excluding the Sith (or other darklings), are there any organizations that train people other than Jedi Knights to use the Force?  Or do the Jedi train people who aren't strong enough in the Force to use it for purposes other than being a Jedi Knight?

If so, who does this and what do they train people to do?

Comment: Sooooorta related:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7297/2242

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> are there any organizations that train people other than Jedi Knights to use the Force?

Yes. Among them:

- [Aing-Tii](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aing-Tii). Unlike the Jedi or Sith, the Aing-Tii (whose species had many Force sensitives) held that the Force had neither a light nor a dark side, but was full of many colors, not unlike a rainbow.

  The Aing-Tii had a different view of the Force from that of other Force-users: they believed that even one who was not Force-sensitive could manipulate the energy field to do his or her bidding. Although Aing-Tii avoided using these "gifts," the monks could instantaneously move an object—ranging in size from small items to 300-meter-long ships—from one location to another, an ability not mastered by even the most powerful of Jedi or Sith. **They were also able to teach this power to non-Force-sensitives**.
- [Fallanassi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fallanassi) were the light side equivalents of Witches of Dathomir.

  There were many Force-sensitive groups NOT affiliated with either Jedi or Sith. "Force-Sensitive" Wookieepedia page lists some of them under "[Independent Force-users](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force-sensitive#Independent_Force-users)" section.

  Also, "[Force-based Organizations](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force-based_Organizations)" contains a full list, though NOT classified by light/dark/Jedi/Sith/independent.

> Or do the Jedi train people who aren't strong enough in the Force to use it for purposes other than being a Jedi Knight?

- As far as I recall, there was at least one trainee in New Jedi Knights order who wasn't a strong Jedi. She was sort of archive keeper/researcher.

Comment: Many Jedi in the Old Republic were not "Knights" as we'd use the term. Yoda, though he could fight, belonged to a sub-sect that preferred to plumb the depths of the Force itself, more a mystic than a warrior. I don't have evidence, but it would seem that the KOTOR could afford to be choosy about the children they took in to the formal training program, while a Jedi's relatively free choice of their Padawan allowed for the incorporation of "outliers"; in all cases, a Jedi decides if another Jedi is to be trained, and that decision is likely made on their potential as a full Knight.

Comment: Not all of the Witches of Dathomir were bad by the way. Tenal Ka's mother was a Dathomir Witch and became the queen of the Hapan Cluster for a time. The Nightsisters were the Dark Siders.

Comment: To say nothing of wild creatures that had ridiculously high force sensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

Emperor Palpatine hand-picked and trained a small group of operatives, the [Emperor's Hands](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Hand) giving them just enough training in the Force to help them carry out their missions. After the Emperor's downfall, most of them went out of their way to make trouble for the Alliance, but one of them (Mara Jade) ended up marrying Luke Skywalker.

Wookieepedia has an article on [Dark Side Adepts](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Side_Adept) that lists a number of people and organizations that used similar ideas (along with a few actual dark Jedi).

As for using such people for good, I don't recall any, and it would make less sense; dark Jedi would want groups not trained enough to pose a threat to them, but that's not usually a concern for light Jedi.