# Why don't Jedi use the force to fly?

Tags: star-wars

If Jedi can use the force to pick up very large objects while performing other actions, what prevents them from using their ability to pick themselves up and fly?

Comment: Jedi **do** use the force to fly: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/can-the-force-be-used-to-fly?rq=1